# Solr: select documents, which contain sprecific term multiple times

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I want to get only those documents which, for example, have term frequency >= N for word 'test_word' in field 'test_field'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [termsComponent](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component) with function `terms.mincount`:

> terms.mincount= - Optional. The minimum doc frequency to return in order to be included. Results are inclusive of the mincount (i.e. >= mincount)

So, you could use a query like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?q=test_word:test_word&terms.fl=test_field&terms.test_mincount=N
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [use a function query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions) by using the `termfreq` function:

> Returns the number of times the term appears in the field for that document.